# How to set Drag Start and End listener on my custom osmdroid map?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I need to display a toast for Drag Events in my map, the below is my code in which i get only **"Drag Started"** message when i do a drag end-event. How can i make it?

```
public void onDragListener() {
    osm.setMapListener(new DelayedMapListener(new MapListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent paramScrollEvent) {
            // public boolean onDrag(boolean b) {
            int drag = DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED;
            if (drag == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Drag Started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            int drag1 = DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED;
            if (drag1 == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Drag Stopped",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
        }

    }));
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I do also have the same issue, looking for a working implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the logic is incorrect it will only show Drag Started Toast. This is how you can fix the toast.

Define variable at class level.

```
    private Context ctx;
```

then assign the value

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_location);


    ctx = getApplicationContext();
```

then use it in your code

```
map.setMapListener(new DelayedMapListener(new MapListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent paramScrollEvent) {
            // public boolean onDrag(boolean b) {
            IGeoPoint ij = map.getMapCenter();
            Double lat = ij.getLatitude();
            Double lon = ij.getLongitude();

           Toast.makeText(ctx, lat+","+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return true;
        }


       @Override
       public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
           return false;
       }

   }));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't fire scroll start/end or zoom up/down directly...
using 'DelayedMapListener' into setMapListener to fire event with delay.
like this:

```
    map.setMapListener(new DelayedMapListener(new MapListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
            //do something
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
            //do something
            return false;
        }
    }, 100));
```